# How can I replicate this zoom in/zoom out effect on a regular image?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/DubCoder/pen/KKwEydp?editors=1100
 So this is the exact image I want, and the exact zoom in/out effect that I want, but because it's on a background image, it seems like I'm not able to move the div around as I normally would.

I've tried wrapping it in a container and moving it around and using margins/padding, but it doesn't work. It either crops off the image or it just doesn't budge.

I want that image to be in the middle of my page, with more content above and below it.

I've tried just putting copying all the code related to animations/transitions and putting it on an image, like so, but then it doesn't work.

```
.myimage {
animation: zoomin 10s ease-in infinite;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
animation: zoomout 10s ease-in infinite;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It starts to change the dimensions of the actual container itself. I need the container to stay the same, whilst zooming in/out of the cabin in the picture.

I'm still pretty new when it comes to animations so if anyone could help, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a main container with `overflow: hidden;`, and inside place your animation like in below example. You can try the following, Run code snippet and move the mouse over the Example word :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    #main-container
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        width: 500px;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #container
    {
        transform: scale(1.0);
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    /* Insert your background image here */
    /* background-image: url(''); */
    }
    #container:hover
    {
        transform: scale(3.0);
    }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-container" >
        <div id="container" >
            <h1>Example</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I edited your code a little bit and got the exact effect I was looking for on my picture. You can see how it looks now here. https://codepen.io/DubCoder/pen/PowLyxB